# Basic Activity Template in Android Studio without menu

Tags: android, android-studio

When I create new project with Basic Activity Template, I have menu in resources and methods in Activity class. But if I create second Activity with the same template Basic Activity, I don't have menu in resources and methods in Activity's class. Why? How to create new Activity with menu automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you right click while in the file tree you can select new activity, and then select basic activity. It should make a new activity with a toolbar and a FAB.

Comment: I talk about menu, but not about toolbar and FAB

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manually import the method for a menu with the given code samples provided. I think if you shift right click or alt right click it will open a dialogue asking what code you want to import and select the menu override from there.

Comment: Excuse me, you read my post? How to create new (second) Activity with menu automatically?

Comment: http://imgur.com/QuRPBUy do this and it should create a new activity with a menu and a toolbar and a FAB.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you do it? I do it in AS 2.1.2 - activity has not a menu.

Comment: I just did it. It works for me, but otherwise i dont know